# ZeroMQ (C): Basic request-reply issue

Tags: client-server, zeromq

Consider the following minimal example of a request-reply setup:

SERVER:

```
// Minimal example request & reply (REQ-REP)
// SERVER

#include <zmq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main (void) {
    //  Socket to talk to clients
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *responder = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    int rc = zmq_bind (responder, "tcp://*:5555");
    assert (rc == 0);

    while (1) {
         char buffer [2];
         zmq_recv (responder, buffer, 2, 0);
         printf ("Received: %s\n",buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

CLIENT:

```
// Minimal example request & reply (REQ-REP)
// CLIENT

#include <zmq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main (void) {
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *requester = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REQ);
    zmq_connect (requester, "tcp://localhost:5555");
    zmq_send (requester, "0", 2, 0);
    zmq_close (requester);
    zmq_ctx_destroy (context);
    return 0;
}
```

Results in the following output:

```
Received: 0
Received: 0
...
```

..and keeps punching this line in standard output forever.

What I would have expected:

```
Received: 0
```

Once.

Obviously, I got the idea of request-reply totally wrong.

---

(20 hours later)

I don't know why. But a back-to-back `zmq_send()` resolves the problem. The following (server) code snippet works as expected:

```
int main (void) {
    //  Socket to talk to clients
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *responder = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    int rc = zmq_bind (responder, "tcp://*:5555");
    assert (rc == 0);

    while (1) {
         char buffer [2];
         zmq_recv (responder, buffer, 2, 0);
         zmq_send (responder, "ACK", 3, 0);
         printf ("Received: %s\n",buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, something seems off there. `zmq_recv()` is blocking, so it's acting like it's receiving the same message over and over - and it should throw an error when trying to receive twice in a row without sending in between. Do you have a separate host you can use to split up the client and server onto separate machines? My first guess is that something got borked in the ZMQ install, so I would try both directions from a different host and see if anything works as expected.

Comment: Thanks @Jason, that will definitely be the next step..

Comment: Instead of receiving it in a buffer, try receiving it in a zmq message (use zmsg_t). See [zmq_recv](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-recv). Repeated zmq_recv invocation means that you have not read all that is to be read from the socket.

Comment: @CatchMeIfYouTry: Thanks for your comment! I don't mind trying out the message functionality. But I expect `zmq_send/recv` to work. Given that I'm implementing it correctly. If repeated `zmq_recv` invocation means that the server hasn't read all there is to read, then I wonder what's missing: Client sends "0\0", server reads "0\0" (otherwise %s wouldn't work since it requires the terminating character).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes sense: a REP socket receives and sends, and a REQ socket sends and receives.

You should try a PUSH socket to send and a PULL socket to receive, in your example.